# Python AttributeError for fibonacci function

Tags: python, attributes

Complete newbie so please be gentle.  I'm working through the Python Tutorial Documentation on Modules and tried to add a third function fib3(n) to the example just to see if I could call it using fibo.fib3(n).  The original fib and fib2 can still be called in the python shell but or some reason fib3 is returning an attribute error `AttributeError: module 'fibo' has no attribute 'fib3'`.  I know I'm missing something rudimentary here but we all have to start somewhere.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

```
def fib(n):    # write Fibonacci series up to n
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b < n:
        print(b, end=' ')
        a, b = b, a+b
    print()

def fib2(n):   # return Fibonacci series up to n
    result = []
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b < n:
        result.append(b)
        a, b = b, a+b
    return result

def fib3(n):   # return modified series
    result = []
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b < n:
        result.append(b)
        a, b = b, a+(b**2)
    return result
```

Comment: maybe you have to reload your module. [mcve] please.

Comment: Is your code properly intended?

Answer (score 0):

As the comments suggest:

- Try reloading your module, and see if it works (most likely case).
- Else, make sure your code is indented properly.

But if you're calling it within the same file, you should just write `fib3(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

it actually works, i tried using "From Fibo import fib3" and "import fibo" and later array = fibo.fib3(4) and it works.
Try to reload the shell.

Answer (score 0):

This is solved.  The problem was I wasn't closing the shell before re-importing the module so it must have been importing a cached version i.e. the previous save and not the fresh save.